# Why running pecl I got /tmp/xdebug.log could not be opened error

Tags: php, xdebug, pecl

I try install under Kubuntu 22.04 of my home laptop Swoole with pecl, but got these errors:

```
running under my project :
root@hoster:/MyProject# pecl install swoole
Xdebug: [Log Files] File '/tmp/xdebug.log' could not be opened.
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
downloading swoole-5.1.1.tgz ...
Starting to download swoole-5.1.1.tgz (2,201,573 bytes)
.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done: 2,201,573 bytes
486 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
root@hoster:/MyProject# cat /tmp/xdebug.log
root@hoster:/MyProject# sudo chmod  755  /tmp/xdebug.log
root@hoster:/MyProject# pecl install swoole
Xdebug: [Log Files] File '/tmp/xdebug.log' could not be opened.
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
downloading swoole-5.1.1.tgz ...
Starting to download swoole-5.1.1.tgz (2,201,573 bytes)
.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done: 2,201,573 bytes
486 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
```

I run command :

```
sudo chmod  755  /tmp/xdebug.log
```

I check configuration :

```
cat /etc/php/8.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

xdebug.start_with_request=yes

zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level=10
xdebug.remote_port = 9003
```

In output of phpinfo I see :

```
Enabled Features
(through 'xdebug.mode' setting)
Feature Enabled/Disabled    Docs
Development Helpers ✔ enabled   ⊕
Coverage    ✘ disabled  ⊕
GC Stats    ✘ disabled  ⊕
Profiler    ✘ disabled  ⊕
Step Debugger   ✔ enabled   ⊕
Tracing ✘ disabled  ⊕
Optional Features
Compressed File Support yes (gzip)
Clock Source    clock_gettime
'xdebug://gateway' pseudo-host support  yes
'xdebug://nameserver' pseudo-host support   yes
Systemd Private Temp Directory  not enabled
Debugger    enabled
IDE Key no value
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.client_discovery_header  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR    HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR
xdebug.client_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.client_port  9003    9003
xdebug.cloud_id no value    no value
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params   On  On
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms   200 200
xdebug.control_socket   time: 25ms  time: 25ms
xdebug.coverage_enable  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host Off Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.log  /tmp/xdebug.log /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level    10  10
xdebug.max_nesting_level    512 512
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.mode develop,debug   develop,debug
xdebug.output_dir   /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.overload_var_dump    (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable    (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.start_upon_error default default
xdebug.start_with_request   yes yes
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.use_compression  1   1
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3

root@hoster:/MyProject# php -v
PHP 8.2.15 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2024 14:17:05) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.15, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.2.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.3.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2023, by Derick Rethans
root@hoster:/MyProject# lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
6.2.0-35-generic
```

What is wrong with my settings ?

Comment: You can check the permissions for `/tmp/xdebug.log`. If it was created by e.g. the PHP interpreter executed through the web server, it'll belong to a different user. Beware that Xdebug logging with level 10 is going to fill up your entire disk sooner or later. You don't need so much information unless you're trouble-shooting an issue with Xdebug itself. In any case, the error you're getting is **phpize: not found**